How to grab an updated preview of all windows that are not minimised (i.e visible on the screen to the user) in python?
Working on a project that blurs a specific object on any visible screen using ML in Python with an overlay, I obviously can't capture the entire screen because when the overlay will be applied the new updated screen will show the overlay which will then cause flickering (because the model sees there is nothing present then removes it but suddenly sees it again and so on...).
Tried to implement a solution myself but got nowhere with it.

Could you give us some more details about the application? Do you have to see the blur red image on your screen or are you transmitting it elsewhere?

Yes so the blur is supposed to be visible to the user on his/hers screen.
